# How can I delete a specific file from a set of results using the find command in Linux?

Tags: linux, find

I have the following command that lists all files with the extension `doc`, `docx`, etc.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname \*.doc\*
```

The command returns numerous files some of which I would like to delete. So for example the results returned are

1. Example.docx
2. Dummydata.doc
3. Sample.doc

I would like to delete Sample.doc and Dummydata.docx. How do I delete the files using the `-exec` option. Am I able to pass in the names of the files e.g. `rm Dummydata.docx Sample.doc` hence the command would look as follows

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname \*.doc\* -exec rm Dummydata.docx Sample.doc
```

Can I pass the names of the files within `{} after`rm`? e.g.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname \*.doc\* -exec rm {Dummydata.docx} Sample.doc
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the names of the files in advance, it'd be easier to just remove them right away:

```
find . -iname "Dummydata.doc" -delete
```

Or, with multiple conditions:

```
find . \( -iname "Dummydata.doc" -o -iname "Sample.doc" \)
```

The parentheses force preference, but you need to escape or quote them since usually, parentheses have a special meaning to your shell.

---

Otherwise if you want to examine the list of results first, you can pass the path of the found files – here, put into `{}` – to `sh`. For the `sh` command, the path will become `$0`, and you can compare it with the name of the file you want to remove:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.doc" \
-exec sh -c 'if [ "$0" == "Dummydata.doc" ] || [ "$0" == "Sample.doc" ]; then echo rm "$0"; fi' {} \;
```

Here, remove `echo` once you're sure the correct file will be removed. But I'm afraid it will be easier to just manually remove the files.

Comment: Passing it to `sh` still assumes I know the name of the file or files doesn't it?

Comment: Of course. But do you know the names of the files you want to remove in advance or not? That aspect wasn't too clear in your question, because if you knew, you could have removed them right away :)

Comment: Sorry. I did not know the names in advance.